# Eclipse IDE Javadoc Hover Tooltip Empty

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse `2023-09 (4.29.0)` and have recently noticed that my hover/mouseover dialog over classes / variables is empty. The text seems to be in the box because I can select and copy paste it (selection is still invisible). Hover boxes with *Dead Code* warnings are still looking fine. I'm not sure what caused the issue.

I can provide the following facts:

- Happens my Debian Linux (Trixie) system with Fluxbox and Nvidia GPU
- Issue also happens with older Eclipse versions (Tested also versions of 2022)
- Issue is unaffected by GTK theme changes
- Issue is unaffected by different Eclipse Theme
- Changing the color in Java -> Editor (Appearance color options) does not affect the box color
- Box is complete white when changing to a light theme

[image: Hover Dialog]

I see the following error in the logs when I try to hover over a field / variable.

```
src/nv_gbm.c:100: GBM-DRV error (nv_gbm_bo_create):
DRM_IOCTL_NVIDIA_GEM_ALLOC_NVKMS_MEMORY failed (ret=-1)
```

I think the problem might be related to my Nvidia driver or something that invokes the driver in a dedicated way.

Any pointers would be welcome since this issue basically renders my Eclipse IDE almost not usable.

Comment: Maybe the web browser widget does not work that is used here (at least I know such a problem when using the Nvidia driver on Linux). Is the _Help > Help Contents_ window shown or is it also empty?

Comment: Yes, it must be the browser widget (webkit?), The help window is also empty. Luckily the env variable I found fixes the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for checking and thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to workaround the issue by starting eclipse via:

`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 /opt/ide/eclipse/eclipse`

I can't provide any further info on this. I found this [thread](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/gamescope/issues/704) and tested the environment variable. I have a two GPU system. Maybe that is confusing the window creation.

Comment: Had the same issue with just one Nvidia GPU, but adding this option also fixed it for me

Comment: This may also be related to the issue: https://github.com/lwindolf/liferea/issues/1308

This may be a webkit bug:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261874