# Eclipse not displaying hovers

Tags: eclipse, hover

I have an issue in my Eclipse : it is not showing hovers.

Ubuntu

Eclipse Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
Build id: 20230907-1323

This is an example of the issue :
[image]

I have the javadoc installed, and when I start eclipse using terminal command, I have these errors when I put my mouse over a class Name :

```
INFO: Registered provider ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider of service org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider in bundle ch.qos.logback.classic
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1x1: Permission denied
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1x1: Permission denied
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1x1: Permission denied
Failed to create EGL images for DMABufs with file descriptors -1, -1 and -1
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1x1: Permission denied
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1x1: Permission denied
KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: Permission denied
Failed to create GBM buffer of size 1x1: Permission denied
Failed to create EGL images for DMABufs with file descriptors -1, -1 and -1
```

I also tried to install a new version Eclispe, a new workspace, and running Eclipse using sudo but nothing worked, I cannot see the hovers, Eclispe won't display them...

Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Is the _Help > Help Contents_ window shown or is it also empty? Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77165391/6505250

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue, it worked after launching eclipse like this

Answer (score 0):

As howlger said I solved it by launching Eclipse this way :

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 /opt/ide/eclipse/eclipse
```